# T-SQL query Fetching data in a single line where multiple rows have similar filters

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table in which I'm having 2 lines with the similar document no. and line no. in which I want the values in a single line in which I can see some values of other lines.

Original dataset

[image]

As attached in screen I have doc no. and line no is same in 2 lines and if I need values from 2nd line that should look like the second screenshot.

Result image should be:

[image]

Comment: How do you decide which line should be used? The GST Comp is different in the lines.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.) What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I have a table in which a document and document line no. exists only once in table A but in another tableB it might occur more than once. The expectation is needed only 1 line from table A  with some columns from table B whether  it contain 3 lines similar to table A like

Comment: I have a table in which a document and document line no. exists only once in table A but in another table B it might occur more than once. The expectation is Values from table A  which matches with table B, Now whether  B contains 3 lines similar to table A(Combination of document no. and line no.), I should be able to take 1 column from first line of B and same column from 2nd line of table B in similar way some column from 3rd line of table B. The same way you can see my result image.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the row_numbers using `row_number()` function based on GST Component or Entry_no as because there are three type of GST's `CGST-SGST-IGST` moreover the other is `UGST` which is related to any union territory.

```
select max(case when entryno = 1 then 1 end) as Entry_no, doc,
       max(case when entryno = 1 then GSTComp end) as GSTComp1,
       max(case when entryno = 1 then [GST%] end) as [GST%1],
       max(case when entryno = 1 then GSTAmt end) as GSTAmt1,
       . . . 
       max(case when entryno = 3 then GSTAmt end) as GSTComp3
from (select *,  row_number() over (partition by doc order by entryno) as seq
      from table
     ) t
group by doc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
          t1.Entry_no
        , t1.doc
        , t1.GSTComp
        , t1.GST%
        , t1.GSTAmt
        , t2.GSTComp as t2.GSTComp2
        , t2.GSTAmt as t2.GSTAmt2
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 
ON t1.doc = t2.doc and t1.lin = t2.lin
```

Try this query